# Vite TypeScript with Qwik (SSR)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, server-side-rendering, vite, ref

I need your help on understanding, I'm contributing to an open-source and feature that is needed is "As a user I want to click on SOMEKEY so that I can focus on the search input so I don't have to do that manually", and I'm having some troubles adding the useRef to the input.

I have basic typescript understanding, and this is the error I get:

"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')"

My code (that triggers the error):

```
const textInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
```

&&:

```
<input
      ref={textInputRef} <== this one
      window:onKeyDown$={(e) => console.log(e.key)}
      onKeyUp$={props.onKeyUp$}
      onInput$={props.onInput$}
      value={state.inputValue}
      type="text"
      id="urlInput"
      class="input input-bordered focus:outline-0 bg-base-200 
flex-auto w-full sm:w-auto mb-2"
      placeholder="Very long url..."
      aria-label="url"
      aria-describedby="shortenerBtn"
    />
```

full code:

```
import { component$, useContext } from '@builder.io/qwik';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { InputContext, Store } from '~/routes';
import { ShortenerInputBtn } from './shortener-input-btn';

export interface ShortenerInputProps {
  onKeyUp$: (event: KeyboardEvent) => void;
  onInput$: (event: InputEvent) => void;
  onSubmit$: () => void;
}


export const ShortenerInput = component$((props: 
ShortenerInputProps) => {
  const state: Store = useContext(InputContext) as Store;
  const textInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

  return (
    <div className="form-control">
      <div class="sm:input-group mb-3 flex-col sm:flex-row gap-2 
sm:gap-0">
        <input
          ref={textInputRef}
          window:onKeyDown$={(e) => console.log(e.key)}
          onKeyUp$={props.onKeyUp$}
          onInput$={props.onInput$}
          value={state.inputValue}
          type="text"
          id="urlInput"
          class="input input-bordered focus:outline-0 bg-base-200 
flex-auto w-full sm:w-auto mb-2"
          placeholder="Very long url..."
          aria-label="url"
          aria-describedby="shortenerBtn"
        />
        <ShortenerInputBtn disabled={state.inputValue.length === 
0} onClick$={props.onSubmit$} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

any suggestion how to bypass that "useRef is null" error?

Comment: Did you conditionally render that input? Or do you have the full code for that component?

Comment: @keikai it is the main text input of the site, I will add right now the full code of that component

Comment: is anyone holding an answer to that?up^

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your issue well, but it seems like you trying to use React `useRef` hook in a Qwik component which is the wrong way to get the refs. I know Qwik uses JSX the same as React but in Qwik, the JSX renders in a different way than React rendering the JSX.

The Right way to use refs in Qwik is like the way below:-

STEP 1: you need to create a signal using `useSignal` to store DOM element like the example below

```
import { component$, useSignal } from '@builder.io/qwik';

const elementRef = useSignal<Element>();

export default component$({
  render: () => {
    return <div ref={elementRef}>Hello, World!</div>;
  },
});
```

STEP 2: Then you need to read the ref using `useVisibleTask$` like example below:

```
import { component$, useSignal, useVisibleTask$ } from '@builder.io/qwik';

const elementRef = useSignal<Element>();

  useVisibleTask$(() => {
    if (elementRef .value) {
      console.log(contanierRef.value);
    }
  });

export default component$({
  render: () => {
    return <div ref={elementRef}>Hello, World!</div>;
  },
});
```